# How to make invoice payment through psql in odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

I want to make payment and convert invoice to paid state through database in odoo10.How can I?

Comment: You can post your try and what error you are facing while doing, so it will be become more easy get the help!

Comment: Actually i unable tomake registerpayment for particular invoice so i am thinking to do from backend(psql)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you wanna do that? you will need to write in several tables in the same transaction like in the account_payment, the account_move records to balance and post the journal entry affecting the accounting taking into account the tax lines and all the involved account_account records ids and be sure that you are affecting the proper accounts with your moves... it's crazy the amount of checks and conditions that you will need to take into account with only sql queries.

To have a better idea you could activate the `log_level = debug_sql` and check all the generated queries when making an invoice payment and that will just be the final result that you wouldn't be able to reproduce it without the debug of the process of post and reconcile of the account moves